# Return a float value from setting plist

Tags: objective-c, jailbreak, theos

I've been trying to pull the value "tempF" from /var/mobile/Library/Preferences/com.skylerk99.snappref.plist to return for the float value.

```
-(float) temperatureDegFahrenheit {
    NSDictionary *pref = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:@"/var/mobile/Library/Preferences/com.sky.snap.plist"];
    NSString *tempF;
    if( [[pref objectForKey:@"showF"] boolValue] ) {
        return tempF;
    }
    else {
        return %orig;
    }
}
```

but I keep getting the error

```
cannot initialize return object of type 'float' with an lvalue of type 'NSString *'
   return tempF;
```

What is the best way to accomplish this, because I obviously don't know?

Comment: What about using floatValue instead of boolValue?

Comment: Your code seems to be incomplete. Is that really all?

Comment: I can't for the life of me understand why so many coders who clearly have never taken an introductory programming course think it's a good idea to start with jailbreak tweaks on iOS.  This is an advanced programming topic.  Not understanding why you can't assign a string to a float is as basic as you get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:**

Based on the discussion below, let's assume the temperature is entered through a `UITextField` called temperatureTextField. You can get the float value of the input temperature like this:

[[temperatureTextField.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]] floatValue];

---

The function expects you to return `float`, but tempF is a `NSString *`.

To parse `float` value from a `NSString`, try this (by the way, I assume that you did not show all your code, otherwise your tempF was never assigned):

```
[tempF floatValue];
```

Comment: okay I figured I needed more. How would I go about assigning tempF. because now now I get the error "use of undeclared identifier 'tempF'"  Sorry if bad place or stupid question, just trying to learn and understand this.

Comment: I guess showF in the plist determines whether to show the temperature in C or F, and it is not the value of the temperature itself. Tell me where the temperature will come from? for example, is it through user input? Tell us what you are trying to do, and we can give you more specific help.

Comment: There's a number input box in the settings pane assigned to the key tempF, there's also an enable switch assigned to showF. So the hope was if showF is set to YES then
-(float) temperatureDegFahrenheit will return tempF value